# GTK+ libgio-2.0.so.0 not installed on the target machine

Tags: linux, gtk, gtkmm

I have an application which uses gtkmm. The client's machine does not have this library installed. When he runs my application on his Red Hat Linux he gets the error:
libgio-2.0.so.0: cannot open share d object file: No such file or directory

How can i install it on the client's machine? I know I can do yum install, but since its Red Hat the client needs an active subscription, but their subscription expired so I'm not able to use yum.

Is there a way to install libgio-2.0.so without using yum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK now I understand what you were trying to say. For anyone who faces a similar problem, this is what i did. 1. Copy the source code of the program to the RHEL machine 2. Compiled the source on RHEL using gcc 3. The binary produced by gcc will work on RHEL

Answer (score 2):

I had to get the same info recently and found it here
http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio

Answer (score 0):

The version of GTK+ on RHEL is too old; it does not have gio at all. Rebuild the binary on RHEL or one of its workalikes.

Comment: it does not have GCC installed even, so I can not compile from source either.

Comment: I did not say "compile it on the target machine". Get RHEL or a workalike, install it locally, and build.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but the machine already has RHEL installed. That machine does not allow me to download anything using yum.

Comment: Ignorance is not the issue here. Put it on one of YOUR machines.

Comment: I have a Fedora 12 machine. What are you suggesting me to do? Rebuild the binary of libgio on my Fedora machine and copy it to the RHEL machine? If that's so how do i do that?

Comment: OK now I understand what you were trying to say. For anyone who faces a similar problem, this is what i did.

1. Copy the source code of the program to the RHEL machine
2. Compiled the source on RHEL using gcc
3. The binary produced by gcc will work on RHEL